# How do I run a dynamic query in select Oracle?

Tags: oracle

I need something like this:

```
begin
for group_level in (select * from group_level)
loop
execute immediate 'select :gost from erp_trips' using group_level.gost_id;
end loop;
end;
```

Group_level is a table in which gost_id is the name of the field that you need to get from erp_trips(in this case 'GOSB')

Code is executed but the table does not output, what is the problem?

Comment: Field and table names can't be specified as bind variables - concatenate them.

Comment: @Dornaut, Could you provide a code snippet describing your idea

Comment: Code snippet for concatenating strings in SQL? `res_string := string1'||myvariable||'string2';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
DECLARE
  p_sql  CLOB;
  c_cur  SYS_REFCURSOR;
  p_gost VARCHAR2(200);
BEGIN
  FOR p_row IN (SELECT gost_id FROM group_level) LOOP
    IF p_sql IS NOT NULL THEN
      p_sql := p_sql || ' UNION ALL ';
    END IF;
    p_sql := p_sql || 'SELECT ' || p_row.gost_id || ' AS gost FROM erp_trips';
  END LOOP;
  OPEN c_cur FOR p_sql;
  LOOP
    FETCH c_cur INTO p_gost;
    EXIT WHEN c_cur%NOTFOUND;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( p_gost );
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE group_level ( gost_id ) AS
SELECT 'GOSTA' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOSTC' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'GOSTD' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE erp_trips ( gosta, gostb, gostc, gostd ) AS
SELECT LEVEL || 'A', LEVEL || 'B', LEVEL || 'C', LEVEL || 'D'
FROM   DUAL
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;
```

Outputs:

> ```
> 1A
> 2A
> 3A
> 4A
> 5A
> 1C
> 2C
> 3C
> 4C
> 5C
> 1D
> 2D
> 3D
> 4D
> 5D
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6e18a4b0ba8c5962749d3780f467ff3b)*

Comment: Thanks, but when I add a second field(p_sql := p_sql || ' select ' ||  p_row.gosb_id' || ', ' || p_row.org_id || 'from erp_trips') I get an error that inconsistent datatypes: expected -got-.

Comment: @МарсельАбдуллин I don't have your tables, data or any idea what you are trying to achieve with that comment. If you want to extend the question then please [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and include a [MRE] with everything needed (table structure, sample data, description of the problem and expected output) to answer the problem.